# Is it possible to append a structure at a particular offset in its derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Just wanted to ask if it's possible to append a struct at a particular offset, in its derived class?

Example -

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct B : A
{
    int c; // place this before b?
};
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have a packet sent to a client, in the newer version of the client, the packet has an extra field. I want to support both versions of the client.

Comment: You don't really have control where in memory those structs are placed. This sounds like an [XY Problem.](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You need to implement proper (de)serialization instead of assuming a specific member order. Your approach, even if it was possible, is doomed to fail.

Comment: If the "packets" are transmitted as the raw structures in binary form, then I really suggest you make two structures, one for each version of the protocol.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will need to do that, thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller Could you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: Please, note that structures may be subject of packing and alignment. If this should be a portable solution, endianess of members could become an issue as well. Hence, I would recommend _to implement proper (de)serialization_ as @Storyteller already did.

Comment: even without your current issue you cannot rely on the structure having same layout in memory

Comment: I googled a bit and found this which might be of interest: [Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without changing the `A` struct unfortunately. You can achieve this by making the `A` struct more customizable:

```
template<typename T = void>
struct A {
    int a;
    T c;
    char b;
};

template<>
struct A<void> {
    int a;
    char b;
};

//           v------ Adds the int as the C member
struct B : A<int> {};

//           v----- Add no member
struct C : A<> {};
```

Comment: Nice - should be denoted, though, that padding might still differ on different platforms (i. a. `A<double>` might have four padding bytes on 64-bit system, but none on 32-bit system).

Answer (score 3):

No you can't circumvent the way a compiler is required to order the members.

But you could base a solution on

```
template<typename A> struct B
{
    int c;
    A a;
};
```

And you could instantiate an instance with say

```
B<A> foo;
```

Even then though, there may be *padding* between `c` and `a`.

Comment: @eerorika: It switches `c` and `a` around in memory cf. the way the OP has it in the question.

Comment: Is the order of the members switched only if the class is instantiated from a template?

Comment: @eerorika: Indeed, if you use `B<A> foo;` then the address of `foo` is the same as the address of `c`, and the `A` struct members appear after.

Comment: why not `struct B { int c ; A a;  };` ?

Comment: @user463035818: Because I wanted to generalise it, rather like the `B : A` of the question is in a sense generalised.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought, but I think this is what eerorikas comment was refering to and I also needed a second to understand why it is a tempalte

Comment: Hm, OK, `c` is before `A.b` now, too... I assumed, though, user wanted to place `c` *in between* `A.a` and `A.b`...